# Registering additional menu in child theme

Tags: wordpress, menu, themes, registering

I have trying to register additional menu location in child theme function.php like below. But menu location not getting displayed in admin panel. I am doing something wrong?

```
function hb_register_slider_menu() {

    register_nav_menu('slider-section-menu', __('slider-section-menu', 'hbthemes'));

}
add_action('init', 'hb_register_slider_menu');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using this way?

```
<?php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'slider_section_menu' );
function slider_section_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'slider-section-menu', __( 'Slider Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
}
?>
```

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu